# Assigning result columns set to variables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'd like to assign the results from two columns to two variables.  I have several TSQL statements inside of a cursor loop block.  When the @currentId (current row Id), is equal to the max(col1) in tablea, I want to get the value of tableb.col2.

```
SELECT MAX(col1), b.[col2] from tablea ta JOIN tableb tb on ta.id = tb.id
WHERE ta.id = @currentId
```

The above doesn't work of course.  Additionally, I'm not sure how to retrieve the values of col1 and col2.  Data types are:

```
col1 int
col2 bit
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use GroupBy as you are using MAX which is an Agreegate Function.

```
Declare @valCol1 INT, @valCol2 INT

    SELECT @valCol1 = MAX(col1), @valCol2 = b.[col2] from tablea ta JOIN tableb tb on ta.id = tb.id
    WHERE ta.id = @currentId

PRINT @valCol1
PRINT @valCol2
```

Note: Above query will fail if the query returns multiple rows.